# acf() function at lag.max = 0

Tags: r, time-series

This might be a very simple question, but what exactly is calculated when acf lag.max = 0?

When lag.max = 1, I am assuming it is only calculating the autocovariance (when type = "covariance") given the previous observation, such that given an observation at time t, it is checking covariance with observation at t-1, for all observations. So what is the number generated when lag.max = 0? I notice it is very close to the actual variance of the data, but not precisely the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acf function using  type = "covariance", compute the covariance for your data at lag 0 up to lag = lag.max. If lag.max is 0, the output of 'acf(your_data,lag.max = 0, type = 'covariance')' will be actually the same to compute the covariance of your data with cov: 'cov(your_data,your_data)'. The numerical difference is because acf round down the significants number by default. Also to know in essence "acf"  using  type = "covariance" compute the function "cov" moving the start point of your data in the second argument like this:

```
 n <- length(your_data)
 cov(your_data[1:(n-nlag)],your_data[(1+nlag):n]) # for lag nlag
```